# Unable to set attributes of UI components (ADT bug or SDK Bug)

Tags: android, android-layout, adt

I am using ADT bundle for android development since long time ,but now a days I am facing some strange problem and I don't know why this occurred. I am unable to set property of UI elements form property panel.Problem:

1.There should be option for true or false with align parent property(But it is not clickable).

2.Also I can not give value of margin or padding from here.

**3.All I can set is only text , width and height.**

Please suggest me what is going wrong? How can I rectify it?

[image]

**All attributes are disable.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the screenshot is for the TextView please review the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) for the xml attributes of that view.

You will notice that the ones that are greyed out in your screenshot are not actual attributes that belong to TextView. Use attributes that belong to that class to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Its not about only text view it's about every UI component,and all also all these component are attributes of textview, I can set those attributes form xml code and it reflects the UI.

Comment: @VibhorBhardwaj Some things to double check: your SDK level in your manifest, update your ADT, update your SDK. Update your IDE (for Android Studio)

Comment: I have to set all attribues from XML